# Pulseaudio doesn’t start

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio

Pulseaudio is not starting after a Xubuntu release upgrade (22.04).

- `pulseaudio --check` returns nothing
- `pulseaudio -D` starts the deamon and sound is working, but I need to restart my web browser to listen to in browser sound, and it still doesn’t start at startup.
- I have `start-pulseaudio-x11` in my startup applications, but when I run this command manually, it returns `pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused`
- I usually use [Carla patchbay](https://kx.studio/Applications:Carla) to have an overviwe of my sound system. But now it is blank.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: @guiverc I edited my question, it is a  release-upgrade.